# Problem to run Flutter app in Android emulator

Tags: flutter

I have a problem running a Flutter app in Android emulator:
[raster snapshot of dev session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwYjZ.png)

> Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\RIZMAN\…

I have searched but could not solve this problem. This problem has occur after the newer android studio version. Flutter app is running on web but issue in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

To run a Flutter app in an Android emulator, make sure the emulator is properly configured and running, the Flutter app is configured to run on the emulator, dependencies are installed, and the Android SDK and platform tools are up to date. Check that firewall or antivirus software is not blocking the emulator or app, reset or create a new emulator, and restart your computer or try a different emulator if needed.